# How to select a column in pandas based on a name?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

[image]I'm trying to select a column.

So I work with the iris dataset. I want to only have the setosa flower for now so I stored it in a variable called `Setosa`.

`Setosa = iris_df[iris_df['Name'] == 'Iris-setosa']`

Then I used the df function because I wanted a specific column.
`Setosa = df['SepalLength']`

Now I made a trace, I want to create a `scatterplot`. X-axis for `sepallength` and Y-axis for `sepalwidth`. But I don't know how to specify that I want it to be on the Setosa flower only?

```
trace1 = {
    "x": `df['SepalLength']`, 
    "y": `df['SepalWidth']`,
```

I first tried `"x": Setosa = df['SepalLength']` and `"y": Setosa = df['SepalWidth']` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the data are you using? Without it, is difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: `df` is not a function. It is though the most commonly used variable name for a DataFrame. You can as well use `DonaldTrump` instead of `df`. I think you need `iris_df` here instead of `df`

Comment: mmm, I remember working with this dataset on datacamp (=, try `iris_df.loc[iris_df['Name'] == 'Iris-setosa']`

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks for pointing that out, it still doesn't work even though I changed it to iris_df

Comment: @Datanovice Yeah I already have it sorted now by the iris-setosa but I want to select the SepalWidth column

Comment: `iris_df['SepalWidth'].loc[iris_df['Name'] == 'Iris-setosa']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this as an answer since it worked

```
iris_df['SepalWidth'].loc[iris_df['Name'] == 'Iris-setosa']
```

Short explanation,

you wanted to return a series where it matched a certain condition, to do this you need to first select the column with either bracket or dot notation and use a `.loc` or another filter to match your condition.

best of luck